# Reading a file on python

Tags: python-3.x

```
my_file = open('file.txt')
next_line = my_file.readline()
while next_line != "":
    print(next_line)
    next_line = my_file.readline()
```

This code is correct and it reads one line in a file at a time. My question is why do they use  next_line!= '' what does this mean? Then they also say next_line = my_file.readline, what is the purpose of doing that, i don't understand the entire loop.

My other question is how can I change this code so it doesn't skip a line when it prints the lines on a file?

Comment: i have figured out my second question all i have to do is say print(next_line.rstrip())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while next_line != ""` means "while the line is not empty". So, the loop means "print next_line and set next_line to the next line until next_line is empty. When next_line is empty, exit the loop".

Calling `.readline()` on a file object leaves a `"\n"` at the end. So you're actually printing the line + \n, which is why it appears to skip a line.

Try using `print(next_line[:-1])`. This will print every character except for the last one (\n).

Comment: Perhaps past the scope of an introductory use of Python File I/O, but it should be noted that although additional characters like `\r` might be present at the end of each line in a file (depending on the system), Python will treat them all as one `\n` by default.